# nothing is written in a file created from a upstart job

Tags: upstart

I have a program in **/home/me/bin/foo**, typically compiled from :

```
// includes
...
#define PATHNAME "/home/me/bin/bar.txt"

int main ()
{
   FILE* f;
   f = fopen(PATHNAME, "wb"); // I skip the possible error for freshness

   fputs(getenv("HOME"), f);

   fclose(f);

   return 0;
}
```

When I run the program from the directory in non-privileges user mode, the file **bar.txt** is created with */home/me* written inside, that works fine..

.. until now
my upstart configuration file in **/etc/init** looks like the following :

```
start on started tty2
exec /home/me/bin/foo
```

when I restart tty2, the file **/home/me/bin/bar.txt** is well created but nothing is written inside.

I've tried to write something else than **getenv("HOME")**, like a basic string but still nothing.

Why is that happening ? what should I do ?

**update.1 :**
After few hours I just noticed that my pointer to the file was not handled properly..
Anyway except that little misunderstanding, that changes didn't solve my problem.
I still have nothing in the file when I write **getenv("HOME")**.
Why ? the process is executed as the root and getenv("HOME") is intended to write at least '**/root**'

Answer (score 0):

Commands executed by Upstart do not have a HOME environment variable.

I used upstart-socket-bridge on an unrelated project to print the environment variables (u-s-b adds a few special variables)

/etc/init/socket-test.conf:

```
description "upstart-socket-bridge test"
start on socket PROTO=inet PORT=34567 ADDR=127.0.0.1
setuid my_username
exec /bin/sh /tmp/socket-server
```

/tmp/socket-server:

```
#!/bin/sh
outfile=/tmp/outfile
date > $outfile            # Timestamp
printenv >> $outfile
exit 0
```

Trigger the job:

```
$ nc localhost 34567
```

And the output list of environment variables looks like:

```
$ cat /tmp/outfile
Wed Dec 11 07:23:50 CST 2013
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
PORT=34567
PROTO=inet
UPSTART_JOB=socket-test
UPSTART_FDS=12
TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
UPSTART_EVENTS=socket
PWD=/
ADDR=127.0.0.1
```